# Running function in background until completion MinGW + Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, mingw

I'm writing something in C++ which includes a countdown function which sets a value when it reaches 0. I've been researching threads/pthreads/boost threads for a few hours now and I just can't seem to get anything to work, so I'm ideally looking for a walkthrough of what needs doing with my code. I'm fairly new to C++ however concurrency is beyond anything I've looked into before, regardless of language.

The function I want to run in the background is:

```
void Counter::decrementTime(int seconds){
    while(seconds != 0){
        seconds--;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    bool = false;
}
```

It will be being called through something as simple as (this is only for example):

```
void Counter::setStatus(string status){
    if(status == "true"){
        bool = true;
        decrementTime(time); // Needs to run in background.
    } else if (status != "false"){
        bool = false;
    }
}
```

I've tried various things such as `std:thread myThread(decrementTime, time);` along with various other attempts (all headers properly included etc).

If anybody could help me with this I'd appreciate it. I don't need to monitor the function running or anything, all I need it to do is set the `bool` when it gets there. I'm running Windows using the MinGW compiler with `-std=c++11` enabled, and as I mentioned earlier I'd love to have this solved (and explained how it was solved) so I can grasp the concept a bit better!

Oh, and if there's an alternate (and better) way to do this without threads, feel free to share your knowledge too!

Comment: Please elaborate what you exactly try to accomplish, also please explain your logic under conditions like "if (status == "true") ... else if (status != "false") ..."

Comment: @AndyT That's not what it'd be, that's just for example purposes. And I want to carry on doing different stuff whilst `seconds` counts down to 0 in the background. Meaning I can use `while (!bool)` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `std::atomic_bool` as flag, and `std::async` to launch the times in a separate thread:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

std::atomic_bool flag{true};

void countDown(int seconds){
  while(seconds > 0){
    seconds--;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::miliseconds( ?? )); //
  }
  flag = false;
}

auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(countDown, time));

// do your work here, checking on flag
while (!flag) { ... }

f.wait(); // join async thread
```

Comment: Is there something I must do to make async available? Those headers don't seem to do it for me.

Comment: @Zackehh9lives it should be in the `<future>` header. It could be that you don't have the required C++11 for that. You can also launch in in an `std::thread` and call `thread.join()` at the end.

Comment: It's an issue in MinGW even if I have C++11, but I've patched it and it's working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::async and [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) and its method "wait_for" with 0 timeout

Comment: How would I run `decrementTime()` using async?

Comment: std::async(std::launch::async, std::bind(decreentTime, time)). But the idea is that yu don't need any shared bool variable,you can use returned std::future and query if it's completed